# How to check if a process is my descendant (kernel mode)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

Let say I am in a kernel mode and I try to know if a Process with PID is my descendant.

is there a function to check it? or should I make a function that will go like this:

```
PSEUDO CODE:

my_process = get_current(); 
target_process = find_task_by_vpid(PID); 
while (target_process != NULL && target_process != my_process)
   target_process = target_process->parent;
if(target_process!=) //meaning he is one of my kids
    return YES_HE_IS_YOUR_KID;
else
    return NO_HE_IS_YOUR_KID;
```

Comment: What do you mean by  "know if a Process with PID is my descendant" ? If you are at kernel level, no user-space processes are your children...

Comment: let say i call my system-call from some wrapper function, i can get the current process task_stract, for this task_struct i want to know if PID is one of his descendant

Comment: What is a difference between this question and [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894657/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-my-descendant-kernel-mode), posted before?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no built in function to determine if a given pid is a descendant of the current process. You should write the function manually. As you've demonstrated, it's fairly trivial and will be less than 10 lines long.

NOTE. **sometimes when in the kernel, there is no current process**. For example in an interrupt context. So you need to tread very carefully.

Comment: You should also add that this is usually called [atomic context](https://lwn.net/Articles/274695/). Interrupt is one case, and another often encountered case is when you are executing code under acquired spin-lock.